# Type ORM error: "Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias" if use sub query with .skip() and .take()

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, psql

I'm using TypeORM, I have tables **lazada_product** and **lazada_product_sku**, 1 **product** has many **product sku**, table **lazada_product_sku** have field **quantity**, so total quantity of product is **SUM(quantity)** of table **lazada_product_sku**. I want to search product order by **quantity**. So I create this query

```
SELECT
    product."id", sort.*
FROM
    lazada_product product
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku.product_id, SUM ( sku.quantity ) total FROM lazada_product_sku sku GROUP BY sku.product_id ) sort ON sort.product_id = product."id" 
ORDER BY
    sort.total DESC
```

This query work well. So I convert it to typeorm like this

```
const res = this.dataSource
      .getRepository(LazadaProduct)
      .createQueryBuilder('product')
      .leftJoin(
        subquery => {
          return subquery
            .from(LazadaProductSku, "sku")
            .select("sku.product_id", "sort_product_id")
            .addSelect("SUM(sku.quantity)", "total")
            .groupBy("sku.product_id")
        }
        , "sort", "sort.sort_product_id = product.id")
      .orderBy('sort."total"', body.sortValue as 'ASC' | 'DESC')
      .skip(skip)
      .take(limit)
      .getMany()
```

I run this code and get an error: `Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias "sort"`

If I remove 2 lines below, it's work

```
.skip(skip)
.take(limit)
```

Hope someone can help me!